# Is there any way to delete duplicate response stored in Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, duplicates, google-forms

I want to delete duplicated response stored in Google Form. I found there is a way to delete it with response but I'm stuck here. Please help me.

```
 function deleteRes (){
 var responseID = FormApp.openById('FormID').getResponses();
 var id = FormResponse.getId();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID");
 var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
 var r = s.getRange('A:A');
 id.setValue();
 responseID.deleteResponse(responseID);
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry for your uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

If you want to delete duplicates of form responses you could iterate over the array of the resposes and delete the ones that are identical. This piece of code implements what you are aiming for (with self explanatory comments):

```js
function myFunction() {
// get the array will all the responses
var responses = FormApp.openById('Form ID').getResponses();
// compare all the responses with the rest of responses
  for(i=0;i<responses.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<responses.length;j++){
    // If the responses we are comparing are the same and they are different responses
    // (that is why we compare their IDs) then we delete on of the responses
      if(responses[i]==responses[j] && responses[i].getId()!=responses[j].getId()){
        FormApp.openById('Form ID').deleteResponse(responses[j].getId())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that the code haven't work. I have 79 responses stored in my google form but after running code they haven't decrease.

Comment: Are all those responses identical? This works for those responses that are exactly the same. Could you please share a sample of your form (*with no sensitive data*) so that I test the function in your environment as in mine it is working well? Many thanks :D !